# How to print functions with varying function name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function which prints user input as an alphabet pattern. Example: If the user input is A then the output should be A shape made of stars(*)

Here's my code

```py
def letter_a():
    for hz_line in range(4):
        for vert_line in range(4):
            if ((vert_line == 0 or vert_line == 3) and hz_line != 0) or ((hz_line == 0 or hz_line == 2)
                                                                         and (0 < vert_line < 3)):
                print("x", end="")
            else:
                print(end=" ")
        print()


def letter_n():
    for hz_line in range(4):
        for vert_line in range(5):
            if (vert_line == 0 or vert_line == 4) or (vert_line == hz_line):
                print("x", end="")
            else:
                print(end=" ")
        print()


def letter_u():
    for hz_line in range(4):
        for vert_line in range(4):
            if ((vert_line == 0 or vert_line == 3) and hz_line != 3) or (hz_line == 3
                                                                         and (vert_line == 1 or vert_line == 2)):
                print("x", end="")
            else:
                print(end = " ")
        print()


userinput = input()
inputlen = int(len(userinput))
print(inputlen)
for char in range(inputlen):
    print("letter_%s()" % userinput[char], end=" ")
```

As you can see, the output is printing the function's name and not the function. How can this be done?

Comment: Make a dictionary the maps the character to the function. `d={"a": letter_a}; d["a"]()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what you are doing is not the best way of accomplishing this. As @jakub mentioned, a dictionary would be good to use.

You could even do something like this:

```
LETTERS = {
    "A": [
        " xx ",
        "x  x",
        "xxxx",
        "x  x"
    ],
    "N": [
        "x   x",
        "xx  x",
        "x x x",
        "x  xx"
    ]
}

def print_letter(letter):
    for line in letter:
        print(line)

userinput = input()

for char in userinput:
    if char.upper() in LETTERS:
        letter = LETTERS[char.upper()]
        print_letter(letter)
```

Trying to call methods based on their name is somewhat hacky and not something I would recommend unless you really had to. You have to make sure the input you received was correct. What if the input is `a(0-+-==`. It is easier to check a dictionary to see if you support that character (which I do in the `if char.upper() in LETTERS` line).

If you really had to, you could do this:

```
userinput = input()

for char in userinput:
    # access the method
    letter_method = locals()["letter_" + char]
    #call the method
    letter_method()
```

`locals()` (and `globals()`) return dictionaries which you can then use to access variables depending on the scope. (See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals). It's fairly meta programming and I wouldn't start using it at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

use globals() to call the function with a string for the name:

```
userinput = input()
inputlen = int(len(userinput))
print(inputlen)
for char in range(inputlen):
    print(globals()["letter_%s()" % userinput[char]]())
```

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- The printing is handled by your functions `letter_a`, `letter_u`, and `letter_n`. They don't return anything (`None`) and therefore passing them to print won't be useful.
- You are passing `print` a string of the function name, not calling the function. Try the following:

```
...
for c in userinput:
  if c.lower() == 'a':
    letter_a()
  elif c.lower() == 'u':
    letter_u()
  elif c.lower() == 'n':
    letter_n()
  else:
    print(c + " is not a valid character!")
```

I haven't checked the logic in your `letter_` functions, but assuming they are OK, this should work.